# Which axis to choose for rotational kinectic energy?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

When we use work energy theorm in rotataional motion .We write the Kinectic energy  of the roatating particle . I don't know , which axis I have to choose in writing the kinectic energy (Axis about which body is performing rotation or Axis through center of mass of body ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the axis is defined with respect to an inertial frame, it does not matter. In general, that would be the axis about which the body is rotating because the center of mass of the body would not be an inertial reference frame unless the body is freely rotating (axis of rotation goes through the center of mass).

It would help to know a bit more of context as determining which reference frame is inertial might depend on that.